# How can I test if a HttpResponseMessage is an ErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Writing a unit test to hit a controller, the code for the controller is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage InsertByKittyId(.....
    ...
    if (result.Success)
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    else
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Exception(result.Message));
```

In my unit test it should generate an error response with the code:

```
var response = kittenController.InsertByKittenId(123);

Assert that response is an Error Response ?
var exceptionResult = (Error Response)response; ?
Assert.AreEqual("Bad Kitty", exceptionResult.Exception.Message);
```

Is there a way to write the two lines with a ?, or should I be checking to see if the response code is not 2xx instead and ignore the error aspect entirely? If so I will need to find a way to pull out the exception.

Edit:

I am wondering if there is a way to distinguish between CreateResponse and CreateErrorResponse rather than looking at the error code, because in some cases I want to attach an exception and in some cases it is not an 'error' per se.

Otherwise I could just do `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);`

However perhaps there is no difference?

Comment: There should be a `IsSuccess` property on it, no?

Comment: There is, but I guess in some situations there won't be an exception? For example 404 doesn't warrant an exception or an error.

Comment: Well that depends what is exceptional circumstances and what you include in them. You are either setting a `200` or a `500` so why not just assert those exist. Do you really care about the exception being asserted in your test. I expect you're not going to let your 500 exception permeate to the client app (browser or app). They are for internal use only, so I would expect some middleware to extract those out and give no message. (which is what I do)

Comment: Yes, because if I am checking I get an error "Item not found" but I actually get "Cannot connect to database" then my unit test needs to fail appropriately.

Comment: So do you throw those specific exceptions then `ItemNotFoundException` or `DatabaseConnectionException`

Comment: If the answer is yes to any of the above (or should be) then take a look at this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling especially down at the examples bit.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 approaches.

The first is that you can check if the status code starts with "2", it would look something like this.

```
response.StatusCode.ToString().StartsWith("2");
```

The second approach is to use the IsSuccessStatusCode property of the response and check against that.

```
!response.IsSuccessStatusCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode.ToString()[0] == '2');
```

That'll check if it's a 2xx error.

```
Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
```

That'll check more generically if there was a failure.